# WooCommerce get value of attribute

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can I get value of specific attribute in WooCommerce order?

I tried the following code, but I only get the attribute name. How do I get the value of the attribute?

```
$items = $order->get_items();
foreach ( $items as $item )
{
    $product_id = $item['product_id'];
    $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
    $variation_data = get_post_meta( $product_variation_id );
    foreach ( $variation_data as $name => $value ) {
        if ( ! $value )
        {
            continue;
        }
        if ( taxonomy_exists( esc_attr( str_replace( 'attribute_', '', $name ) ) ) )
        {
            $attribute = $variation_data[$name][0];
            $value_of_attribute = ???;
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: `get_post_meta ( int $post_id, string $key = '', bool $single = false )` you can notice you can use the attribute key as argument to get the attribute value.

Comment: With this `get_post_meta ( $product_variation_id, $name);` I get the uri identifier of the variation, but I need the name of the variation.